# Add active / active trail class to main link when click on sub (child) link of menu item like menulink/sublink

Tags: drupal, drupal-7

I have a question about Drupal 7 menu items.
In my main menu in the header I have different menu items: Home, link1, link2, link3, etc.

In the sidebar I have a menu for different links under one link in the page header So for one page link1/link1, link1/link2.

When I click on one of these link in the header main menu there is no active / active-trail class anymore.

How is it possible to assign these classes back again to the header menu item when clicking on underlying links?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest solution would be to assign each page to as a subpage of the main page.

To put it simpler, when saving a page, at the bottom: Create a menu and make it a sub-page in the menu hierarchy.

That way when you are on 2nd level pages, Drupal knows which is the parent page.

Comment: yeah that work, but i dont want to show the link of the subpage in the main menu. I want to show this sublink in a sidebar, and when you click it the main link also gets the active classes

Comment: I guess it depends on your theme because some themes don't show sub pages in the main menu. Anyway the menu system is the correct way of doing what you want. Try http://drupal.org/project/menu_block to display the menu links the way you want.